# Executables show with character * next to their name in output of ls

Tags: shell, zsh, ls

I noticed that when I list my executables with `ls` on my Z shell they show up with a character `*` next to their name  (e.g. see the file in red `.test_color_scheme`)

[image]

What is causing this? I understand the colors are controlled by by `LS_COLORS`? But is `LS_COLORS` also responsible for showing `*` next to their name? or is there anything else that causes this?

**Note:**
I verified this happens to all my executable files, and that the character `*` is not part of the file name (e.g. to open the file I type `cat filename` without the `*` character)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by the `-F`/`--classify` flag on `ls` (as are the `/` after directories, though those can be added independently).  It seems this option is `alias`ed into your `ls`.  If you would like to disable it, you should track down where it is added as an alias and remove it, or add `--indicator-style=none`.

The following options affect these indicators:

```
-F, --classify
    append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries

--file-type
    likewise, except do not append `*'

-p, --indicator-style=slash
    append / indicator to directories

--indicator-style=WORD
    append indicator with style WORD to entry names: none (default),
    slash (-p), file-type (--file-type), classify (-F)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have probably an `alias` for `ls` containing the `-F` option. Something akin to:

```
alias ls="ls -F"
```